# How to use JQuery to select the checked value of a radio button?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, radio-button

I am having an issue I am not able to resolve despite through research and effort. So I am posting it here. I have two input radio button elements with the same name
, which represent `Business Bank Account Service` being used or not:

```
<input type="radio" name="bank_account_service" value="no" checked='checked'>No
<input type="radio" name="bank_account_service" value="yes">Yes
```

Now I also have the following JQuery function which should alert the value of this radio selection:

```js
var  bank=$('input[name=bank_account_service]:checked').val();
$(document).click(function(){alert(bank);});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Business Bank Account<br/>
<br/><input type="radio" name="bank_account_service" value="no" checked='checked'>No
<br/><input type="radio" name="bank_account_service" value="yes">Yes<br/><br/>
```

I want to alert **yes** when the radio button for `Yes` is checked. Can anyone guide me as to what am I missing or doing wrong please?

Comment: The variable doesn't change by itself. You need to change it when the radio change or fetch the value when you need it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might be looking for this:

```js
$('input[name=bank_account_service]').click(function () {
 alert($('input[name=bank_account_service]:checked', '#yourForm').val())
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Business Bank Account<br/>
<form id="yourForm">
<br/><input type="radio" name="bank_account_service" value="no" checked='checked'>No
<br/><input type="radio" name="bank_account_service" value="yes">Yes<br/><br/>
</form>
```

Comment: Yea this is the one, but would you please also explain why did it not work with the $(document).click and why is it working with $('input[name=bank_account_service]').click. Thanks for the help.

Comment: $(document).click listens for clicks to anything in the document.  Totally unnecessary.  You want to be listening to clicks on just specific elements.  (ps, I think my answer does things pretty straightforward too)

Comment: In your code you have, `var  bank=$('input[name=bank_account_service]:checked').val();` which stores `no` in variable `bank` as soon as your document loads since `no` is selected by default. So every time you click on your document, you were getting `no` in the alert. But `$('input[name=bank_account_service]:checked', '#yourForm').val()` will always reference the current value of the radio input.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you've got some of your jquery backwards.

Try this:

```
//all click events go in here
$(document).ready(function(){
     //click event on all of these bank inputs
     $('input[name=bank_account_service]').click(function(){
         //check to see if this is the yes option
         if ($(this).val()=='yes') {
             //do something
         }
     });
});
```

You might also want to consider putting unique IDs for each of your radio buttons.  So if you could change your HTML to this:

```
<input type="radio" name="bank_account_service" value="no" id='bank_no'>No
<input type="radio" name="bank_account_service" value="yes" id='bank_yes'>Yes
```

Then you could make your jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     //click event on only the yes input
     $('#bank_yes').click(function(){
         //do something
     });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<form>
 <div>
   <input type="radio" name="fruit" value="orange" id="orange">
   <label for="orange">orange</label>
</div>
<div>
   <input type="radio" name="fruit" value="apple" id="apple">
   <label for="apple">apple</label>
</div>
<div>
   <input type="radio" name="fruit" value="banana" id="banana">
   <label for="banana">banana</label>
</div>
<div id="log"></div>
</form>

<script>
$( "input" ).on( "click", function() {
  $( "#log" ).html( $( "input[name='fruit']:checked" ).val() + " is checked!" );
});
</script>
```

Try something like this !!!